# I want to get the handle of the control of the telegram desktop version through the C# application

Tags: c#, c, telegram, desktop

I want to get the button handle for the telegram desktop version through the C # application, but the button handle always returns 0. What can I do to get the control handle? This is my source code:

```
IntPtr awintest = FindWindow("Qt5QWindowIcon", null);
IntPtr childPtr = FindWindowEx(awin, IntPtr.Zero, "TWidget", "");
```

Comment: Try playing with things like `EnumChildWindows` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-enumchildwindows and see if you can get it that way

Comment: You might want to consider using _Microsoft UI Automation_ for this sort of thing.  It works for things don't even have handles for child elements such as WPF

Comment: I tried the EnumChildWindows function, but I didn't get any button control information in the telegram

Comment: Sorry, dear Micky D, I don't understand what you mean. Could you elaborate on it